# Flutter: My FlutterToast don't show the text when I submit form

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

I'm new in Flutter and I make an register form for insert and user in mysql. I'm using a "Future async" function with FlutterToast for show text if the registration is successfull or not and this is connected with my register.php archive. I need show the text or show an alert message (How do I put an alert inside the FlutterToast? I tried "msg" instead of "text" but it didn't work).

My function:

```
  Future register() async {
    var url =
        "http://192.167.1.142/databasedb/register.php"; 
    var response = await http.post(url, body: {
      "correo": correo.text,
      "celular": celular.text,
      "passwd": passwd.text,
      "passwd2": passwd2.text
    });
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (data == "Error") {
      FlutterToast(context).showToast(
          child: Text(
        'User invalid',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.red),
      ));
    } else {
      FlutterToast(context).showToast(
          child: Text('Registration Successful',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.green)));
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DashBoard(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

My submit button:

```
Expanded(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        onSurface: Colors.blue,
      ),
      child: Text('Register',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white)),
      onPressed: () => [
        // enabled: isButtonActive,
        if (isButtonActive)
          {
            setState(() => isButtonActive = false),
          }
        else
          {null},
        register(), //REGISTER FUNCTION
        setState(() {})
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

My register.php

```
<?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','databasedb');
    //Conectar al hosting
    if (!$db) {
        echo "Database connection faild";
    }

    $cell= $_POST['celular'];
    $email= $_POST['correo'];
    $pass= $_POST['passwd'];
    $pass2= $_POST['passwd2'];

    $sql = "SELECT celular FROM usuario WHERE celular = '".$cell."' AND passwd = '".$pass."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1) {
        echo json_encode("Error");
    }else{
    
    if($pass == $pass2 && strlen($pass) >= 8 && strlen($email) >= 10 && (strlen($cell) >= 9 && strlen($cell) <= 15)){
        $insert = "INSERT INTO usuario(correo,celular,passwd,passwd2)VALUES('".$email."','".$cell."','".$pass."','".$pass2."')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db,$insert);
        if ($query) {
            echo json_encode("Success");
        }
    }else{
        echo json_encode("Contraseña inválida");
    }
        
    }

?>
```

When I run flutter and submit in Chrome, in console appears it:

```
engine.dart:457 [Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 51ms
:55843/#/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.167.1.142/databasedb/register.php' from origin 'http://localhost:55843' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access to XMLHttpRequest at http://192.167.1.142/databasedb/register.php from :55843/·/:! origin http://localhost:55843 has been blocked by
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Alow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
errors.dart:202 Uncaught (in promise) Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 84:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1687:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 160:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 593:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1288:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37254:58                              <fn>
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (errors.dart:284)
    at Object._rethrow (async_patch.dart:200)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (zone.dart:1413)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49)
    at async_patch.dart:166
DartError @ errors.dart:202
RethrownDartError @ errors.dart:240
createErrorWithStack @ errors.dart:284
_rethrow @ async_patch.dart:200
(anonymous) @ zone.dart:1413
_microtaskLoop @ schedule_microtask.dart:40
_startMicrotaskLoop @ schedule_microtask.dart:49
(anonymous) @ async_patch.dart:166
Promise.then (async)
_scheduleImmediateWithPromise @ async_patch.dart:164
_scheduleImmediate @ async_patch.dart:136
_scheduleAsyncCallback @ schedule_microtask.dart:69
_rootScheduleMicrotask @ zone.dart:1495
scheduleMicrotask @ zone.dart:1707
[_asyncCompleteError] @ future_impl.dart:665
[_completeError] @ future_impl.dart:50
completeError @ future_impl.dart:33
(anonymous) @ browser_client.dart:82
runUnary @ zone.dart:1687
handleValue @ future_impl.dart:160
handleValueCallback @ future_impl.dart:767
_propagateToListeners @ future_impl.dart:796
[_complete] @ future_impl.dart:593
_cancelAndValue @ stream_pipe.dart:61
(anonymous) @ stream.dart:1288
_checkAndCall @ operations.dart:334
dcall @ operations.dart:339
(anonymous) @ html_dart2js.dart:37254
error (async)
[_addEventListener] @ html_dart2js.dart:15814
[dartx.addEventListener] @ html_dart2js.dart:15802
[_tryResume] @ html_dart2js.dart:37284
onData @ html_dart2js.dart:37255
get first @ stream.dart:1287
send @ browser_client.dart:79
(anonymous) @ async_patch.dart:45
runUnary @ zone.dart:1687
handleValue @ future_impl.dart:160
handleValueCallback @ future_impl.dart:767
_propagateToListeners @ future_impl.dart:796
[_completeWithValue] @ future_impl.dart:602
(anonymous) @ future_impl.dart:640
_microtaskLoop @ schedule_microtask.dart:40
_startMicrotaskLoop @ schedule_microtask.dart:49
(anonymous) @ async_patch.dart:166
Promise.then (async)
_scheduleImmediateWithPromise @ async_patch.dart:164
_scheduleImmediate @ async_patch.dart:136
_scheduleAsyncCallback @ schedule_microtask.dart:69
_rootScheduleMicrotask @ zone.dart:1495
scheduleMicrotask @ zone.dart:1707
[_asyncCompleteWithValue] @ future_impl.dart:639
[_asyncComplete] @ future_impl.dart:634
_Future.immediate @ future_impl.dart:283
value @ future.dart:334
forTap @ feedback.dart:107
runBody @ async_patch.dart:84
_async @ async_patch.dart:123
forTap @ feedback.dart:97
[_handleTap] @ ink_well.dart:988
invokeCallback @ recognizer.dart:198
handleTapUp @ tap.dart:608
[_checkUp] @ tap.dart:296
handlePrimaryPointer @ tap.dart:230
handleEvent @ recognizer.dart:563
[_dispatch] @ pointer_router.dart:94
(anonymous) @ pointer_router.dart:139
forEach @ linked_hash_map.dart:21
[_dispatchEventToRoutes] @ pointer_router.dart:137
route @ pointer_router.dart:123
handleEvent @ binding.dart:439
dispatchEvent @ binding.dart:419
dispatchEvent @ binding.dart:322
[_handlePointerEventImmediately] @ binding.dart:374
handlePointerEvent @ binding.dart:338
[_flushPointerEventQueue] @ binding.dart:296
[_handlePointerDataPacket] @ binding.dart:279
invoke1 @ platform_dispatcher.dart:1020
invokeOnPointerDataPacket @ platform_dispatcher.dart:184
[_onPointerData] @ pointer_binding.dart:130
(anonymous) @ pointer_binding.dart:558
(anonymous) @ pointer_binding.dart:511
loggedHandler @ pointer_binding.dart:217
```

The text isn't showing at all in my view, **but submit successfully into database**

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Can you share more details of what the problem is exactly? Is the toast showing but without text? Or it isn't showing at all? What response are you getting from the server? Also, I suggest using HTTP status codes to determine success or error states instead of plain text

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is that I can't show in the view the text of `FlutterToast(context).showToast` from the function `Future register() async` when I submit, but I can submit my form in my DB perfectly. The error in console when I submit now is in the question right now.

Comment: Ooooh - I see, in your console, you're getting a CORS error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as though you are getting a CORS error from your server. Try adding the to your response (in PHP):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Now it works!!! I'll share my code :D

Comment: Don't works in AndroidStudio `D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 6148): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
E/flutter ( 6148): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (onError): Error handler must accept one Object or one Object and a StackTrace as arguments.: Closure: (HttpException) => Null ` Only work in chrome :(

Comment: So the first error you posted about _was_ a CORS issue (on the PHP side). This is a different error, in the way your Flutter app is handling the response from your server. These are 2 different things.  I suggest that you post another question for this particular issue

Comment: Thanks! I will post another question :)